# Why is my UIButton not displaying on my view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uibutton

I have a iOS5 project using storyboard and with ARC on.

I have a view in storyboard with the class thisViewController and in there I got a smaller subview which I dragged in and gave it the class thisView.

thisView has a custom drawRect function, that works and draws what I want nicely.
But I also want to add buttons dynamically, so I'll add them in the initWithFrame method of thisView like so:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"This is called <3");
        UIButton *btn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [btn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:btn]; 
        [self bringSubviewToFront:btn];   // last thing I tried, didn't work, thought z-index was to low or something
    }
    return self;
}
```

The function is being called since the NSLog displays, but the button is nowhere to be found

--EDIT--

Extra information:

ThisView.h

```
@interface RadarView : UIView <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `[self.view addSubview:btn];`   ?

Comment: @janusfidel The I get an error 'property view not found on object of type ThisView* .But that's normal right? Cause the object itself is a view? no?

Comment: it depends on what superclass you have, what is your superclass here?

Comment: @janusfidel I updated the question with my .h file

Comment: If you've added radarview in the storyboard, it will be created using initWithCoder, not initWithFrame. Are you sure that log message you are seeing is actually from the initWithFrame method?

Comment: I found what the problem was, there was an init in the radarviewcontroller, which triggered initwithframe, which made the NSLog display, and the initwithcoder wasn't used so I didn't see anything, that was the problem and got stuff mixed up. Thanks for commenting and helpin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was thanks to some comments and the chat

There was an init in the radarviewcontroller, which triggered initwithframe, which made the NSLog display, and the initwithcoder wasn't used so I didn't see anything, that was the problem and got stuff mixed up. Thanks for commenting and helpin!

Answer (score 0):

Dont add the SubView in the init method.
Add the SubView in the `- (void)layoutSubviews`.

```
    - (void)layoutSubviews {
         [super layoutSubviews];

         if (![self viewWithTag:12345]) {
            UIButton *btn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
            btn.tag = 12345;
            btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [btn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self addSubview:btn]; 
         }
    }
```

Comment: This definitely should work. There is no necessity of down voting this. If you have to downvote, then do post the reason. Be man enuf to do atleast so much.

Comment: Nobody has to explain downvotes. But this method will add a new button every time the view is resized - for example, if the device is rotated.

Comment: You should add conditions to check if the subview is already available. example : `if (![self viewWithTag:12345]) { UIButton *btn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50); btn.tag = 12345; [self addSubview:btn];}` This restricts the "btn" with tag "12345" to be added everytime there is any interaction on the view.                 Updated the code above accordingly.

Comment: And now your code looks terrible and has several unneeded lines. layoutSubviews is for laying out subviews, not adding new ones. awakeFromNib or initWith... methods are the place for adding new subviews.

Comment: It dint work in his init method so I suggested this. If it works, good for him. I definitely dont have any problem. But on a flipside, if he has 5- 10 subviews to be added on the view, the init method is definitely going to look real dirty.

Comment: but like you say, if init is the right place to do this. I would definitely take this as a learning and look into it going forward..

Comment: IMO the problem is he should be using initWithCoder: rather than initWithFrame:, but no response to comment yet!